# Django extended model instantiation

Tags: python, django, model

I've extended my User model thusly:

```
class Common(User):
    #common attributes

class Employee(Common):
    #employee specific members

class Client(Common):
    #client specific members
```

At this point my `User`s can log in without any issue, and I'm about ready to start putting together specific methods for these classes (checking managerial groups, departments, etc).  So my question is this:

What is the recommended way to instantiate an extended model?  Can/should I do it inline into a single object or do I need to keep them separate?

```
my_employee = Employee.Create(Common.Create(Request.User))
```

OR

```
my_Common = Common.Create(Request.User)
my_Employee = Employee.Create(my_Common)
```

This could be a question that shouldn't really be coming up, but I'm teaching myself both Django and Python at the same time, so I'm still rather new to both.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ shows how to do the creation of these models, but not how to actually USE them.  Which is what I'm after.

Comment: I've been reading about this recently and the latest documentation suggests using AbstractBaseUser when extending the User model.  (There seem to be a number of approaches.  I haven't decided what I'm going to do yet though...) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @monkut I looked at that same documentation before making the decision to extend rather than using a custom model. My extended data has nothing to do with authentication, so I made the decision to use joins rather than replacement.